# G-ds name online

Tags: halacha, words, technology, sin, divine-names

On a google doc during an assignment with friends who do not understand the intricacies of Judaism, someone wrote g-d's names pronunciation, I did not realize what I was doing and deleted it, was this wrong to do, I do not believe so as it is not a permanent form of g-d's name, but I am not exactly sure

Comment: Did someone delete G-d's name? In my last comment, I wrote "God." I thought there was a halacha. Hence this question..........

Comment: Yes they wrote the pronunciation of the Tetragrammaton

Comment: I don't think we no longer know the pronunciation of the Tetragrammaton. When the Masorites added vowels Jews retained the consonants without pronunciation of the Tetragrammaton.